# Resolve Classpath within Eclipse as Maven-Plugin

Tags: eclipse, maven, maven-plugin, tycho

**Enviroment**

I am developing a Maven-Plugin for multimodule build which is using Eclipse Tycho. One of the plugins tasks is a bytecode enhancement and requires the maven projects classpath.
At the moment I am adding all `session.getAllProjects()` and `project.getArtifacts()` to the `ClassRealm` of my `PluginDescriptor`. This works just fine from the CLI on the parent and child pom.

**Problem**

If I am trying to build in eclipse (update on one of the projects) maven doesn't resolve the compilepath within the plugin - I only get the plugin classpth (at least in the usecase within eclipse). This leads to an error.

**What I've already tried**

- Using `requiresDependencyCollection = ResolutionScope.RUNTIME_PLUS_SYSTEM, requiresDependencyResolution = ResolutionScope.RUNTIME_PLUS_SYSTEM` in my Mojo Annotation
- Getting the classpath from some other variables available

**Questions**

1. How is the best way to get the whole maven build classpath in my plugin?
2. Does the classpath behaviour have anything to do with tycho?

Any post will be appreciated! Thank you very much!

Comment: What do you mean by: `maven doesn't resolve the whole classpath...` What is in your opinion the whole classpath? What kind of project do you have? Multimodule project? Furthermore manifest first / pom first configuration in Tycho ?

Comment: Yeah it's multimodule. I have poms in all projects but I let tycho read the manifest for the dependencies. By `whole classpath` I mean projects mavens compilepath. I only get the classpath for the plugin (at least in eclispe otherwise it already works)

Comment: My list of Reactor Projects seems to be null in case of building from eclipse. Otherwise this list is set. Does this have anything to do with the behaviour above?

Comment: If you let tycho do the reading of the MANIFEST files which contains the dependencies than you can't ask Maven to solve that cause it's related to Tycho...This will be a hard thing..I would ask on the dev list of the tycho maven project in Eclipse...

Comment: Yeah maybe should just ask over there. The strange thing is that it's possible to resolve manifest dependencies through the CLI Build and even dependency:tree shows them. Thank you very much!